# preg replace_callback mentions and hashtags in post

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Lets say i have a text,

```
$text = '@stackguy @flowguy I need to learn more advanced php #ilovephp';
```

I want to replace both @stackguyand @flowguy with those 2 anchor tags respectively. This should also work for any number of @'s in the text string.

```
<a href="url/stackguy">@stackguy</a>
<a href="url/flowguy">@flowguy</a>
```

I also want to replace #ilovephp with

```
<a href="search/ilovephp">#ilovephp</a>
```

It should also work for multi #'s. I'm guessing it'll be something like

```
preg_replace_callback('regex',
            create_function('$matches', '
                switch ($matches[1]) {
                    case "@":
                        return "<a href=url.$matches[2]'/'>" . $matches[2] . "</a>";
                    case "#":
                        return "<a>" . $matches[2] . "</a>";
                }
        '), $var);
```

What's the regex going to look like?
Is my function going to match all what's needed or do i need to add a foreach loop?
Thanks.

Comment: Sooo... what's the question?

Comment: Why are you "guessing it'll be something like" whatever?  Try it and then if it doesn't work, then we have something to go off of.  You've come thisclose to actually writing some code and trying it out.

Comment: The most important part of the func(the regex) is something i have no clue about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wan't to match text preceded by @ or # use this: `/([@#])(\S+)/`

View this demo: http://regex101.com/r/eP7eU0

Note: this will match the same thing when it's inside tags. If you don't want that, you're going to need more than regex.

Comment: Might want to amend that to `/([@#])(\S+)/`.  Saffron needs to match the symbol to determine which anchor tag to wrap it in.

Comment: Thanks @lindrian and Gigawatt: Does the function replace all or do i need a loop?

Comment: @SaffronHarris: `preg_replace()` loops automatically, you don't have to do that yourself.

Comment: @lindrian: what do you mean by matching the same thing when inside tags? you mean if i have <p>the same text</p>, it would output the same result?

Comment: @SaffronHarris: If you run the regex against a string already formatted with the `<a href="blah">@stackguy</a>` stuff it will match those contents again.

Comment: Thanks for your help @lindrian, i'm implementing it now.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks again @lindrain. How do i add more things to tthe regex eg +,* and http? Also any good regex tuturial you could recommend?

Comment: @SaffronHarris: I don't know what you mean when you say add more things. Create a new question in due time :). I recommend http://www.regex101.com/quiz/. You can also pick up a old fashioned book, something like Mastering Regular Expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just meant if i also wanted to find and replace + and http's in the text would the regex look like this /([@#+https?://])(\S+)/

Comment: @SaffronHarris I recommend `[^\s#@]` instead of `\S` for the possible cases of multiple consecutive # or @ signs like `##sometag`, `#@someone`, `@@someone` etc.

Comment: Thanks alot @inhan, that doesn't affect the normal case right?

Comment: Also do you know how to avoid cases like [at]someone's or [at]someone: or @someone., it shouldn't read the ',: and .? Thanks

Comment: @SaffronHarris nope, that won't affect the normal case. `\S` indicates "anything but a space of any type" so if you're sure you want to match only, say alphanumeric characters then you can use `\w` instead of `\S` or `[^\s#@]`. Note that `\w` (word character) matches a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and underscore (_). You can always limit it down to your desired character group, like `[a-zA-Z]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]` etc. In anyway don't forget the plus sign to catch as many characters as possible, like in Lindrian's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace()` and `preg_replace_callback()` both, by default, look for all the possible matches so you don't need a loop.

Considering these values have not already been wrapped by anchors, I would use either

```
preg_replace('~@([^\s#@]+)~','<a href="url/\1">$0</a>',
    preg_replace('~#([^\s#@]+)~','<a href="search/\1">$0</a>',$text)
);
```

or

```
preg_replace_callback('~([#@])([^\s#@]+)~',create_function('$m',
    '$dir = $m[1] == "#" ? "search" : "url";' .
    'return "<a href=\"$dir/$m[2]\">$m[0]</a>";'
),$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this [tutorial on replacing hashtags and mentions](http://theoryapp.com/find-and-replace-hashtags-and-mentions-in-php/), preg_replace() is good enough.

```
$patterns = array('/#(\w+)/', '/@(\w+)/');
$replacements = array('<a href="http://example.com/tag/$1">#$1</a>', 
                '<a href="http://example.com/user/$1">@$1</a>');

$html = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```